# SSH tunneling between two server

Tags: ssh, usermod

I'm  trying to create SSH tunnel between two VPS for Secure MySQL Replication.
I follow these steps (read only Step 1: Setup SSH Tunneling):
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-mysql-replication-using-ssh-on-a-vps
Both servers are with Ubuntu 14.04 OS.
The problem occurs when I try to create the tunnel on my Slave machine, when I run:

```
ssh -L 33061:localhost:3306 tunneluser@1.1.1.1 -f -N
```

I get this respone:

```
This account is currently not available.
```

I did some tests. If i try to connect from Slave to Master with

```
ssh 'tunneluser@1.1.1.1' //before to execute: usermod -s /sbin/nologin tunneluser
```

it works, so my keys are correct. It seems that the problem is in this step:

```
usermod -s /usr/sbin/nologin tunneluser
```

First time when I tried this it had been working fine, but I can't reproduce it againg. I'm using the same images of my VPS's, I follow same steps, there is no difference in the environmnet, what cloud be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake!

The problem was in MS Word, I saved all commands in a doc file and just copy and paste them. MS Word converts regular `-` to longer `–` in some cases. So, this longer dash breaks my last command:

```
ssh -L 33061:localhost:3306 tunneluser@1.1.1.1 -f -N
```

OMG, I lost 8 hour about that!

Comment: *Very* common flaw, but extremely hard to detect.

Comment: Sheesh, don't use MS Word for this, for that reason and *many* others. There are plenty of very capable plain-text editors that will not try and do anything "clever" with your code like Word so helpfully does.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the line in the instructions you're following that said:

> Debian and Ubuntu users replace /sbin/nologin with /usr/sbin/nologin

Your tunneluser account thus has no valid shell, and you can't log into it.

Comment: Actually I didn't, I did **/usr/sbin/nologin** as in tutorial. I have done mistake in my question, sorry, I will edit it, thanks.